# Convert from DEC PDP-11 or Honeywell 316 to big endian unsigned int

Tags: c, endianness

How can i convert unsigned int variable to big endian if my endian is DEC PDP-11 or Honeywell 316 in C?

Would it be correct to convert my unsigned int running on pdp endian to big endian like this:

```
unsigned n = 12;
n = ((n << 8) & 0xFF00FF00UL) | ((n>>8) & 0x00FF00FFUL);
```

let say my endian is Honeywell 316 how can i convert the variable n to big endian? can you please show me

Comment: You need to shift all 4 bytes, not just 2 bytes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Barmar. Do you mean my code for pdp endian to big endian is wrong? do you know how to convert from Honeywell 316 to  big endian?

Comment: @Barmar: Their code is shifting all four bytes, presuming `unsigned` is four bytes. The Honeywell 316 and PDP-11 were [middle-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian), at least in some uses of four-byte integers on them.

Comment: Convert from the source of the data. Integer variables themselves don't have endianness.